# SVG <use> elements won't scale

Tags: css, svg

I have a couple elements defined in a `<def>` tag and am trying to use them in `<use>` tags in my app.  I can't remember how to scale those elements to the size I want them to be.  In my `index.html` file I have this in my body.

```
<svg class="illustrations" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="15.974158px" height="11.492275px" viewBox="0 0 15.974158 11.492275">
  <defs>
    <path id="wBottomA" d="M5.195663,6.086151L4.6133,8.093828L3.982081,6.086151H1.912755l1.699042,5.406125h2.052177
            L7.24307,6.086151H5.195663z M12.156589,6.086151l-0.582363,2.007678l-0.631154-2.007678H8.873102l1.699619,5.406125h2.052176
            l1.575532-5.406125H12.156589z"/>
    <path id="wTopA" d="M5.537079,4.909111L6.961057,0h2.068698l1.54328,4.909111H8.503049L8.02812,3.398447L7.586863,4.909111
            H5.537079z M14.543463,4.909111L15.974158,0h-2.052176l-1.423978,4.909111H14.543463z M3.612011,4.909111L2.068567,0H0
            l1.542834,4.909111H3.612011z"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

in the `illustrations` class I just set a `display: none;` property to keep it invisible on the screen.

The way I'm trying to use this in my nav bar is like this.

```
<svg class="wContainer">
    <g>
        <use href="#wTopA" fill="hsl(var(--gray-500), 1)" />
        <use href="#wBottomA" fill="hsl(var(--yellow-500), 1)" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

The `wContainer` class sets `height: 92%; aspect-ratio: 1/1;` which works, but I can't figure out how to get the `#wTop` and `#wBottom` to fill in the space.  I've tried adding the `preserveAspectRatio` and `viewBox` settings on the `svg` tag in my `navbar` component, I've tried adding height and width properties directly on the two elements, nothing has worked.  How do I get them to scale with the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalable templates in SVG are called `<symbol>`. These container elements can have `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` attributes, but their grafical content is not rendered. But when they are referenced by a `<use>` element, the content is shown, with the size of the referencing `<use>` element, and as if it had the `viewBox` and the content of the `<symbol>`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
.wContainer {
    height: 92%;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
.illustrations {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.wContainer use { /* these are default values */
    x: 0;
    y: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<svg class="illustrations">
  <symbol id="wBottomA" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 15.974158 11.492275">
    <path d="M5.195663,6.086151L4.6133,8.093828L3.982081,6.086151H1.912755l1.699042,5.406125h2.052177
            L7.24307,6.086151H5.195663z M12.156589,6.086151l-0.582363,2.007678l-0.631154-2.007678H8.873102l1.699619,5.406125h2.052176
            l1.575532-5.406125H12.156589z"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="wTopA" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 15.974158 11.492275">
    <path d="M5.537079,4.909111L6.961057,0h2.068698l1.54328,4.909111H8.503049L8.02812,3.398447L7.586863,4.909111
            H5.537079z M14.543463,4.909111L15.974158,0h-2.052176l-1.423978,4.909111H14.543463z M3.612011,4.909111L2.068567,0H0
            l1.542834,4.909111H3.612011z"/>
  </symbol>
</svg>
<svg class="wContainer">
    <g>
        <use href="#wTopA" fill="gray" />
        <use href="#wBottomA" fill="yellow" />
    </g>
</svg>
```